# Query for all documents when any of the array element is found in a field in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a document like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "active": true,
    "key": []
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "active": true,
    "key": [
      {
        "code": "fake_code",
        "ids": [
          ""
        ],
        "labels": [
          "d"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "active": true,
    "key": [
      {
        "code": "fake_code",
        "ids": [
          ""
        ],
        "labels": [
          "a",
          "b",
          "c"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I only want to get the `id` of the documents in which any of the values of the given array(let's say ["a", "b", "c", "d"]) present in `labels` field in the documents.

That means, since the given array = ["a", "b", "c", "d"], and if you will see the documents, then you can find the document having `id = 2` is having ["d"] in the `labels` field, and the document having `id = 3` is having ["a", "b", "c"] in it's `labels`.

So, the expected output is like,

```
[
  {
    "id": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 3
  }
]
```

Currently, I've been using

```
db.collection.find({
  "key": {
    "$all": [
      {
        "$elemMatch": {
          "ids": {
            "$in": [
              ""
            ]
          },
          "code": "fake_code",
          "labels": {
            "$in": [
              [
                "a",
                "b",
                "c"
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
},
{
  _id: 0,
  id: 1
})
```

This query is able to return me only one document having `id = 3`, because in this case I am using the given array = ["a", "b", "c"]. But is it possible to get all documents according to the given array(like ["a", "b", "c", "d"]), that means if any document is having at least one matching values of the given array then the query should return the `id` of those documents?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know if I've understand well, because I've understand [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pRHEYh2YYl6). If it is ok I can explain in an answer

Comment: Hey, I have an array like ["a", "b", "c", "d"]. and I can not write like 
`$in: [ "a", "b", "c", "d"]`. I have to write like `$in: [["a", "b","c", "d"]]`. So can you tell me if we can use any other query selector in any way to achive this?

Comment: I dont understand why do you write something like `$in: [["a", "b","c", "d"]]`

Comment: Actually, in my case I am using pymongo. And I am getting an array(Like in the question, i have referred it as given array). And I need to get the output like mentioned in the question. I hope you are getting me.

Comment: if you get an array like `[ "a", "b", "c", "d"]` , whydo you add it again inside another array? you can directly pass it, no!! if im not wrong. And sorry if Im wrong, im not a python guy

Comment: Hey, thanks. You were right. It helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$in`. I fyou dont have any condition inside `$elemMatch`, you can directly access `"key.labels":{$in:[....]}`

```
db.collection.find({
  key: {
    $elemMatch: {
      labels: {
        $in: [
          "a",
          "b",
          "c",
          "d"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
},
{
  _id: 0,
  id: 1
})
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0cMoGDI_hJq)**